# Clipping LiDAR Data to Map Data w/ LAStools bounding boxes have no overlap

Tags: lidar, lastools, nad83

I am trying to clip a series of LiDAR .las files with the lasclip64 tool in LAStools. The area I am trying to clip is Prospect Park in Brooklyn, NY. I have retrieved the .shp file for this area from this data

https://nycopendata.socrata.com/Recreation/Parks-Properties/enfh-gkve

I imported the data into python and searched the eapply (name of property) column for prospect park and took the corresponding multipolygon (I beleive this is a sql datatype) and saved it to a shp file. Viewing it with QGis all is well and good.

My next step was to grab the LiDAR data and use LAStools to clip the LiDAR data to these bounds. I used [this tool](https://orthos.dhses.ny.gov/?Extent=-9603624.133747088,4774299.7366908705,-7659066.134172721,5795498.434580554&Layers=07_meter_dem_index_usgs,1_meter_dem_index_fema,1_meter_dem_index_usgs,1_meter_dem_index_tidal_water,1_meter_dem_index_hydro_flattened,1_meter_dem_index_usda_utm18n,1_meter_dem_index_usda_utm17n,1_meter_dem_index_nys,2_meter_dem_index_ne_lidar,2_meter_dem_index_nys,2_meter_dem_index_fema,2_meter_dem_index_monroe_county,2_meter_dem_index_tompkins_county,2_meter_dem_index_erie_county&layerGroups=DEMIndexes,Orthoimagery&rightMenu=0#) to download the tiles from the 2017 LiDAR.

Now, the LiDAR data is in NAD83 horizontal, NAVD88 Geoid 12B and projected in New York State Pland - Long Island (US ft) and the .shp file (from what I can figure out) has no CRS(?).

```
 .\lasclip64 -i 992175.las -poly prospect_park.shp -v


Please note that LAStools is not "free" (see http://lastools.org/LICENSE.txt)
contact 'martin.isenburg@rapidlasso.com' to clarify licensing terms if needed.
creating clip polygon took 0.001 sec.
WARNING: bounding boxes of 'prospect_park.shp' and '992175.las' have no overlap
         'prospect_park.shp' has bounding box:
         [-73.9794,40.6513] to [-73.9621,40.6724]
         '992175.las' has bounding box:
         [992500,175000] to [995000,177500]
WARNING: unlicensed. over 3 million points. output slightly distorted.
         tiny xyz noise. points permuted. intensity, gps_time, user_data
         and point_source_ID zeroed.
removed points 9283956 (0). outputting 0 points took 0.013 sec.
removing empty output file '992175_1.las'
done with '992175_1.las'. total time 0.013 sec.
```

I understand that the boxes do not overlap, but how do I fix this issue?

Comment: Have you tried to apply EPSG:4326 to the shape file?

Comment: If there is no .prj file then there is no georeference, if there is a .prj file open it with a text editor and you will find the WKT of the defined spatial reference. If you do set your unknown shapefile coordinate reference system to WGS84/geographic then confirm it is in the expected location with your choice of QGIS, ArcGIS, Global Mapper, MapInfo ... I'm not sure that LASTools will transform your shapefile into NAD83/feet, you might need to project it into the same CRS as your LiDAR data. Either way **license your LASTools**, using it unlicensed will warp your data slightly.

Comment: Hey. Thank you all for the information. I have projected the shape file to EPSG: 4326 in QGis. When I open the shapefile and view it in QGis it is in the correct location. I can also (for a reason I do not understand) open the LAS file in QGis (under its projection 2263/ New York long Island ftUS) and it also appears in the correct location. But when I do the cliplidarto polygon (I am now using whitebox tools) there is no output file. I am assuming this is because it tries to project both files to the same coordinate sysyem and they do not overlap.